# Problem with separating Real and Imaginary parts for fmincon (constrained MATLAB optimization). How to program it correctly?

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve this optimization problem with ***fmincon*** function in **MATLAB**:

[image]

Where all H are complex matrices, g and Pdes are complex column vectors, D0 and E0 are numbers.

I expect to get complex column vector of g (and in general its should be  complex), So I divided problem in two parts: real and imag, but it does not work, MATLAB returning me a message:

```
Not enough input arguments.

Error in temp>nonlincon (line 17)
c(1) = norm ( H_d*([g(1)+1i*g(4); g(2)+1i*g(5); g(3)+1i*g(6)]) )^2 - D_0;

Error in temp (line 12)
        = fmincon(objective,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],nonlincon);
```

Where I am wrong?

And in general am I right in writing given problem in the following way:?

```
% For example:
D_0 = 2*10^(-5)*10^(60/10);
E_0 = 50;
H_b = rand(15,3) + 1i*rand(15,3);
P_des = rand(15,1) + 1i*rand(15,1);
H_d = rand(10,3) + 1i*rand(10,3);

    objective = @(g) (norm ( H_b*([g(1)+1i*g(4); g(2)+1i*g(5); g(3)+1i*g(6)]) - P_des ))^2;                        
x0 = ones(1,3*2)';
options = optimoptions('fmincon','MaxFunctionEvaluations',10e3);
[X,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,LAMBDA,GRAD,HESSIAN]...
        = fmincon(objective,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],nonlincon);

% So I expect to get a column vector g: 1st 3 elements - Real part, next 3 - Imag

function [c,ceq] = nonlincon(g, H_d, E_0, D_0)
c(1) = (norm ( H_d*([g(1)+1i*g(4); g(2)+1i*g(5); g(3)+1i*g(6)]) ))^2 - D_0;                        
c(2) = (norm ([g(1)+1i*g(4); g(2)+1i*g(5); g(3)+1i*g(6)]))^2 - E_0;
ceq = [];
end
```

Comment: Is there anything that suggested you that you are wrong? Have you tried it? "it does not work" ? that is very ambiguous

Comment: Yes sorry, I reformulated

Comment: Read the documentation. the input fucntion of `fmincon` (in your case you named it `nonlincon`) need to have only 1 input argument. you made it with 4

Comment: I read again...Maybe I dont understand smth.: "Nonlinear constraints, specified as a function handle or function name. nonlcon is a function that accepts a vector or array x and returns two arrays, c(x) and ceq(x)."

Comment: Maybe you don't understand indeed. "nonlcon is a function that accepts a vector or array x". What does it accept? 1 vector or array `x`. So it has only 1 input. you are giving it 1 vector of array (`g`) and then other 3 more, so 4 in total. That does not work, it has to be 1.

Comment: Ah, thanks! but even if I put all my variables calculation inside a function or use a global variables it does not work. The same error. Does it mean that  nonlcon function cant have other matrices, even with numbers?

Comment: ...even if I delete everything from nonlcon function and leave only one variable g - does not work and the same error...

Comment: you can not just change everything randomly and hoe it works because it *technically* fits the rules. You need to take a bit more time to learn what youa re doing

Comment: Thanks but already took several times in several days and cant figure out what is wrong, that's why asking here

Comment: I dont even understand your problem. `H_d` shoudl be your system matrix, did you just make it random? that is then a random problem you are solving, not sure if you can learn anything from that. If you create a system of equations of the form Ax=b and you give everything random values, you may be create a completely unfeasible problem. So yeah, you need to sit back and learn a bit more of what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify that `nonlincon` is a function of variable g only when calling `fmincon`

## The code is as follow

```
[X,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,LAMBDA,GRAD,HESSIAN]...
        = fmincon(objective,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],@(g)nonlincon(g, H_d, E_0, D_0));
```

## Solution X

```
X = [0.2982; 0.1427; 0.3597; -0.0729; -0.1187; 0.2090]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my inattention about syntax